# Error: XModel is not associated to Ymodel on Sequelizejs

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a few weeks working with Sequelize and I ran into this. I've already read other similar questions but nothing seems to help.

Let me show you my models:

Merchants.js
    'use strict';

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var config = require(__base + '/server/config/config').provisioning;
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.user, config.password, config);

var Merchants = sequelize.define('merchants', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING(255)
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    field: 'created_at'
  },
  //more attributes
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function (models) {
      Merchants.hasOne(models.Users, {foreignKey: 'merchantId'})
    }
  }
});

module.exports = Merchants;
```

Users.js

```
'use strict';

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var config = require(__base + '/server/config/config').provisioning;
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.user, config.password, config);

var Users = sequelize.define('users', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
  },
  merchantId: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    field: 'merchant_id'
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    field: 'created_at'
  },
  // more attributes
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function (models) {
      Users.belongsTo(models.Merchants, { foreignKey: 'merchantId' });
    }
  }
});

module.exports = Users;
```

Then I'm trying to do this:

```
Users.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Merchants,
        where: { state: 'ACTIVATED' }
    }]
  }).then(function (users) {
    console.log(users.length);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

And I'm getting: `[Error: merchants is not associated to users!]`

I've done some of the stuff I've read in different questions but nothing seems to work. It might be a foolish thing, but as I said before, first time working with Sequelize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the associations are actually being set up - Do note that the `associate` method is not part of sequelize API, but is merely a common pattern - *you* have to make sure its actually called. For example with:

```
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
```

https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js

Comment: This makes total sense. How dumb I am. And it worked, THANKS!